# MOSFET motor driver burns up with battery

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, robotics

I am working on a robot. I have used a MOSFET bridge to drive the motors. The problem is that when I test the motor drive using a power supply the circuit works fine without any problem but when I connect the battery it initially when motor is not driven nothing happens but as soon as the drive command is given the MOSFET burns.
Can this problem be due to battery or due to any problem in circuit? Please let me know if you can help regarding this issue.

Comment: Please include specifications and schematics for your setup. Thanks.

Comment: The average LiPo or lead acid battery will give more current than your bench supply. You’ve told us little about your circuit so we can only guess what the problem might be.

Comment: The desk supply limited your current so nothing burnt out. When using a battery, there was no current limit so the current limiter was the resistance of the stalled motor (often very low) which is usally a lot more than the FET can handel.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said anything much about how you're driving the MOSFET, but the three most likely problems are:-

- You are overloading the MOSFET with too much current. That may be the case if your new battery is capable of delivering very high currents.
- The MOSFET needs a heatsink, but you haven't given it one.
- You are not fully switching the MOSFET on. Check the gate voltage against the manufacturer's data sheet.